# Cannot open Workflows list after deleting a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, delete, workflow-history

I deleted a workflow from SharePoint designer and now whenever I try to open the Workflows dialog on a list item it gives me the "An unexpected error has occurred" box. I suspect that this is because the workflow history that shows in this box is now corrupted and pointing to an old workflow that is no longer there. I restored the workflow from the recycle bin but I am still getting the error.

Another change that I had made that could be causing the issue is I deleted all of the initiation form parameters that were multi-line text boxes and recreated them as single line text boxes. I do not believe that this could cause the issue though.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have figured it out. The answer is below in case anyone else runs into the issue:

I looked at the logs for the error and found this:

> System.ArgumentException: Column 'PC1Rerou' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

If you delete a workflow and re-add it you need to **run the workflow manually after you restore it** in order to recreate the hidden list column for that workflow. After I did this I was able to open the workflows on all items that previous had that workflow associated with it.

Comment: "If you delete a workflow and re-add it you need to **run the workflow manually after you restore it** [...]" needs clarification: If you cannot reach the workflow dialog page in SharePoint, how are you supposed to run it. Sorry for not using this field properly. As I cannot write a comment because I don't have 50 reputation, I am forced to disregard the "But *avoid* ..." portion of this field's usage parameters.